# Splitting pages into multiple files in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

First of all, I'm quite a noob so please excuse me if I ask stupid questions, or if the same question has already been answered elsewhere: I might not know the rights terms to effectively search for a topic.

So here's my problem. I'm trying to create a dashboard using Polymer. Therefore, I'll have a nav bar / menu with many option (contracts, calendars, admin page...). While looking at the polymer starter kit and its demo, we are told to put all the pages related to the navigation drawer within the index.html file, between `<section>` markups.

However, these pages may contain a lot of code, and there will be many pages (12 at the moment). I fear the index.html will soon become humongous, which will probably mean "hard to maintain" and "long loading time".

So my question is the following: is there a way to easily split the page app into multiple html files? Like creating a new custom element and importing it in the header, then using it between the `<section>` markups?

---

Okay so, following the advices I've been given here, I've read about HTMLimport, and the tutorial about "Lazy loading" on Chrome developpers' youtube and here's what I did (it is based on polymer starter kit). Problem: it does not work :(
Clicking on "Contracts" in the navbar does nothing. I don't get it :/
Help me please!

```
 <!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>My awesome page</title>
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">
</head>

<body unresolved>
<!-- build:remove -->
<span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>
<!-- endbuild -->


<template is="dom-bind" id="app">           
    <paper-menu class="app-menu" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
    <a data-route="contracts" href="{{baseUrl}}contracts">
        <iron-icon icon="description"></iron-icon>
        <span>Contracts</span>
    </a>

</paper-menu>
<div class="content">
    <iron-pages id="iron" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
    <section data-route="contracts" tabindex="-1">
        <page-contracts id="contracts"></page-contracts>
    </section>

    <!-- lots of other <section> here -->

</iron-pages>
</div>
</paper-scroll-header-panel>
</paper-drawer-panel>
</template>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the routing element:

```
<script src="../bower_components/page/page.js"></script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

    // We use Page.js for routing. This is a Micro
    // client-side router inspired by the Express router
    // More info: https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/

    // Removes end / from app.baseUrl which page.base requires for production
    if (window.location.port === '') {  // if production
      page.base(app.baseUrl.replace(/\/$/, ''));
    }

    // Middleware
    function scrollToTop(ctx, next) {
      app.scrollPageToTop();
      next();
    }

    function closeDrawer(ctx, next) {
      app.closeDrawer();
      next();
    }

    function setFocus(selected){
      document.querySelector('section[data-route="' + selected + '"] .page-title').focus();
    }

    // Routes
    page('*', scrollToTop, closeDrawer, function(ctx, next) {
      next();
    });

/* other routing here */

    page('/contrats', function() {
      if (Polymer.isInstance(this.$.contrats)) {
        app.route = "contrats";
        return;
      }

      Polymer.base.importHref(
        "/page-contrats/page-contrats.html", function() {
          app.route = "contrats";
          return;
        }
      )
    });

/* other routing here */

    // 404
    page('*', function() {
      app.$.toast.text = 'Impossible to find: ' + window.location.href  + '. Redirecting to dashboard';
      app.$.toast.show();
      page.redirect(app.baseUrl);
    });

    // add #! before urls
    page({
      hashbang: true
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: What is a "page" in "all the pages related to the navigation drawer". What is "between markups"? If "Like...creating a new custom element and importing it in the header, then using it between the markups?" is the question, than yes, usually you have a file per component and just import it. You can wrap a set of components in another component and then just import and add this one to get all it's content shown. Please clarify your question and what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe HTML Imports could help you modularize your site. It offers a way to include and reuse HTML documents in other HTML documents. Search for `html imports` and `web components`. Polymer is built on top of Web Components - so this should be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Your routing page needds to look like this:

```
<script src="../bower_components/page/page.js"></script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

    // We use Page.js for routing. This is a Micro
    // client-side router inspired by the Express router
    // More info: https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/

    // Removes end / from app.baseUrl which page.base requires for production
    if (window.location.port === '') {  // if production
      page.base(app.baseUrl.replace(/\/$/, ''));
    }

    // Middleware
    function scrollToTop(ctx, next) {
      app.scrollPageToTop();
      next();
    }

    function closeDrawer(ctx, next) {
      app.closeDrawer();
      next();
    }

    function setFocus(selected){
      document.querySelector('section[data-route="' + selected + '"] .page-title').focus();
    }

    // Routes
    page('*', scrollToTop, closeDrawer, function(ctx, next) {
      next();
    });

/* other routing here */

    page('/contrats', function() {
      app.route = 'contrats';
      setFocus(app.route);
    });

/* other routing here */

    // 404
    page('*', function() {
      app.$.toast.text = 'Impossible to find: ' + window.location.href  + '. Redirecting to dashboard';
      app.$.toast.show();
      page.redirect(app.baseUrl);
    });

    // add #! before urls
    page({
      hashbang: true
    });

  });
</script>
```

In your elements.html you need to import the page:

```
<link rel="import" href="/page-contrats/page-contrats.html">
```

And your enement needs to look like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../elements.html">

<dom-module id="contrats">

  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles"></style>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
        <your-code-here>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      Polymer({
        is: 'contrats',
      });
    })();
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Hope I helped.